# React ts and react-media-recorder

Tags: reactjs, web-mediarecorder

I have small problem with WebPack after added `react-media-recorder` from this npm lib -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-media-recorder

when I try run app, then I have error from webpack

```
  ERROR in ./node_modules/rxjs-interop/dist/esm/to-observer.js 11:42
    Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:42)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
    |         }
    |         return {
    >             complete: (observer.complete ?? noop).bind(observer),
    |             error: (observer.error ?? rethrow).bind(observer),
    |             next: (observer.next ?? noop).bind(observer),
     @ ./node_modules/rxjs-interop/dist/esm/index.js 3:0-30 3:0-30
     @ ./node_modules/subscribable-things/build/es2019/module.js
     @ ./node_modules/extendable-media-recorder/build/es2019/factories/webm-pcm-media-recorder.js
     @ ./node_modules/extendable-media-recorder/build/es2019/module.js
     @ ./node_modules/react-media-recorder/lib/index.js
     @ ./node_modules/react-media-recorder/index.js
     @ ./src/tools/ScreenRecording.tsx
     @ ./src/menu/DrawersWrapper.tsx
     @ ./src/views/VideoEditor.tsx
     @ ./src/views/AuthRouter.tsx
     @ ./src/index.tsx
     @ ./src/entrypoints/web/main.ts
```

So generalyy I installed by npm, use similar to example

```
import { useReactMediaRecorder } from "react-media-recorder";

const RecordView = () => {
  const { status, startRecording, stopRecording, mediaBlobUrl } =
    useReactMediaRecorder({ video: true });

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{status}</p>
      <button onClick={startRecording}>Start Recording</button>
      <button onClick={stopRecording}>Stop Recording</button>
      <video src={mediaBlobUrl} controls autoPlay loop />
    </div>
  );
};
```

this section is in `webpack.config.babel.ts`

```
rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            cacheDirectory: true,
            plugins: [
              (isDevelopment && isUsingDevServer)
                ? require.resolve('react-refresh/babel')
                : null,
            ].filter(Boolean),
          },
        },
```

I use React 16.14.2

Had someone similar problem or know where is problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think this error comes from [extendable-media-recorder](https://github.com/chrisguttandin/extendable-media-recorder/issues/652), but I go back to v1.6 and work well

`"react-media-recorder": "1.6.0"`

Comment: Thanks! I have the same issue and downgrade to 1.6.0 resolves the issue